# Как получить названия выбранных элементов checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно чтобы в соседнем блоке выводились `label` выбранных элементов. Подскажите как это реализовать?

```js
$( '.ctf--b-filt-check-list input' ).on( 'click', function() {
  // Считаю кол-во выбранных элементов
  $( '#log' ).html( 'Выбрано: ' + $( 'input:checkbox:checked' ).length );
  
  array = [];
  // перебираю выбранные элементы и добавляю их в массив
  for (i=0;i<$( 'input:checkbox:checked' ).length;i++) {
      array.push( $( 'input:checkbox:checked' )[i] );
  }
  // Вывожу выбранные элементы
  $( '#msg' ).html( 'Названия: ' + array );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_0" value="11772">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_0">
      <i></i>
      ЗУБР
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_1" value="11780">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_1">
      <i></i>
      ИСТОК
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_2" value="11785">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_2">
      <i></i>
      DELTA
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Comment: попробуй взять Html из лейбла и отрезать  `<i></i>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var label = $('.ctf--b-filt-check-list label'),
  checkbox = $('.ctf--b-filt-check-list :checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var checked = checkbox.filter(':checked');
    $('#log').html('Выбрано: ' + checked.length);
    var labelText = checked.map(function(i, el) {
      return label.filter('[for="' + el.id + '"]').text();
    }).get().join(',');
    $('#msg').html('Названия: ' + labelText);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_0" value="11772">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_0">
            <i></i> ЗУБР
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_1" value="11780">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_1">
            <i></i> ИСТОК
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_2" value="11785">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_2">
            <i></i> DELTA
        </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Легкая модификация Js кода позволяет это сделать.
 В примере реализация в лоб, я использовал JQuery [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

```js
//полифилл
if (!String.trim) {
  (function() {
    // Вырезаем BOM и неразрывный пробел
    String.trim = function(item) {
      return item.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
    };
  })();
}

// сама функция
$( '.ctf--b-filt-check-list input' ).on( 'click', function() {

$( '#log' ).html( 'Выбрано: ' + $( 'input:checkbox:checked' ).length );  
var arr =  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
            .siblings()
            .filter('label');
  
if(arr.length===0){
    return;
} 
//простой вариант
var text = $(arr[0]).text().trim(); 
for(var i =1; i<arr.length;i++){
  text += ","+$(arr[i]).text().trim();    
}

//более лаконичный
/*
var text = arr.map(function(i,el){
  return $(el).text().trim()
})
.get()
.join(' ,'); 
*/

// Вывожу выбранные элементы
$( '#msg' ).html( 'Названия: '+ text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jspContainer" style="width: 193px; height: 500px;">
      <div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; left: 0px; top: -275px; width: 180px;">
        <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list">
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_0" value="11772">
            <label for="idchkk_2_1_0">
              <i></i>
              ЗУБР
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_1" value="11780">
            <label for="idchkk_2_1_1">
              <i></i>
              ИСТОК
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_2" value="11785">
            <label for="idchkk_2_1_2">
              <i></i>
              DELTA
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="log"></div>
        <div id="msg"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```